# Move Closure from ViewController to ViewModel

Tags: swift, mvvm, closures

The following snipped code is located in my `SettingViewController` and want to move `LocationManager.locationUpdated` closure logic into `SettingsViewModel`. I am stuck how to manage it.

**SettingsViewController.swift**

```
private let settingsViewModel : SettingsViewModel()

func updateLocationButtonClicked() {
 if isLocationUpdateNeeded() {
       CustomLocationManager.locationUpdated { success in
         if success {
           self.updateMap()
         } else {
           DispatchQueue.main.async {
             // add an alertview here
           }
         }
       }
     } else {
        updateMap()
     }
 }
```

Comment: And what about the `updateMap()` method?

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of ways to implement it

You can add function properties to your viewModel:

```
var locationUpdateDidSucceed: (() -> Void)?
var locationUpdateDidFail: (() -> Void)?
```

Then, you can bind these method in your VC:

```
settingsViewModel.locationUpdateDidSucceed = { [weak self] in
    self?.updateMap()
}

settingsViewModel.locationUpdateDidFail = { [weak self] in
    self?.displayAlert()
}
```

And finally add logic to your viewModel:

```
CustomLocationManager.locationUpdated { [weak self] success in
    if success {
       self?.locationUpdateDidSucceed?()
    } else {
       self?.locationUpdateDidFail?()
    }
}
```